# Primefaces : How to update a grid/table in the parent form from a command button on the child form in a dialog (dialog residing on the parent form)?

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I want to update the table with id "datatable" by pressing the button with id "updator". The XHTML code is as follows :-

```
<h:form id="mainForm">

    <p:datatable id = "datatable"> 

        ---- columns ----

    </p:datatable>

</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" >

    <h:form id="subForm">

        various input fields
        ......  
        ......
        <p:commandButton id="updator" actionListener="#{javaBean.updateGrid()}" update="mainForm:datatable" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>

    </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

Comment: You can use primefaces `p:component()` function. This function finds component in view root with the given ID and then returns its client ID. For your case: `update=":#{p:component('datatable')}"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `update=":mainForm:datatable"`

Comment: @user3236167: Did you have the `:` before `mainForm`?

Comment: It worked, actually there was some backend exception. Thanks a lot for replying ! :)

Comment: But you should strictly avoid nested forms

Comment: Then what should I use to achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: @user3236167: what you show in your example code is fine. There're no nested forms. Don't worry :). Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted though ;)